# Finding minimum tuple value satisfying a given condition

Tags: python, tuples

I have some tuples: `(0,1,2)`, `(3,4,4)`, `(2,2,2)` and I would like to find the minimum of the the zero index such that the second index equals `2`. I have tried this using the `min` built-in function but it is giving me a syntax error.

```py
min(data, key=lambda x: x if x[2] == 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the key parameter. If you want to ignore certain elements in finding the minimum, use `filter()` instead:

```py
data = [(0,1,2), (3,4,4), (2,2,2)]

print(min(filter(lambda x: x[2] == 2, data)))
```

This outputs:

```py
(0, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You should pass a generator expression to `min` which filters the list accordingly.

```
>>> data = [(0,1,2), (3,4,4), (2,2,2)]
>>> min((x for x in data if x[2] == 2), key=lambda x: x[0])
(0, 1, 2)
```

Of course, the default behavior of `min` on a list of tuples of numbers like this means that explicitly keying `min` on the first element of the tuple is not necessary, though it does possibly make the intent of the code more explicit.

```
min(x for x in data if x[2] == 2)
```